# Is it pretty easy to predict the stock market from price/sales?

Tags: equities

Except the recent boom (entirely driven by tech) isnt the stock market just an oscillator around quarterly price to sales? I'm getting like 25% explained variance just from that.

The returns are close to market but that's just because most quarters have been up.

Comment: You're looking at previous quarter's sales? Or do you have a way to guess at this quarter's sales?

Comment: Previous quarter or even projection from past earnings

Comment: It seems fairly likely, given your explained variance of 25%, that your analysis contains some look-ahead bias (from the point of view of prediction models).  The question from @kurtosis is hinting at this, because it is very different to predict where prices will go in the future based on what you know now than to observe a correspondence between some P/S variable and contemporaneous returns.  From a _prediction_ point of view, the explained variance that counts is from out-of-sample predictions and their corresponding outcomes.

Comment: When you say you explain 25% of variance do you mean that you predict next quarter's price and the variance of the difference between your prediction and next quarter's price is 25% of the variance of next quarter's price? Or, do you mean the variance of the difference between your prediction and next quarter's price is 25% of the variance of the price change between quarters? Ideally, you should be looking at returns to assess your performance and the amount of variance explained.

Comment: I can send you the excel is pretty simple. It works nearly every quarter except recessions. Data is 2000 to present quarterly.

Comment: If it was lookahead the correlation would be positive and  not negative (more valuation menas more price). Variance is over 3 month subsamples and averages to 25%.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning, 'as a measure of intrinsic value, cant you use P/S to predict, loosely, future stock price movements'?

Not even close at the index level, and certainly not at the stock level.  Not sure how you've set up your regression to get an R2 of .25 with P/S as your only independent variable, but I'd almost guarantee there's an issue with your calculation.

Even asserting P/S is a robust estimator of intrinsic value is subjective.  Most factor definitions of value use a combination of attributes (inclusive of P/S, P/B, P/CF, among others) because individual attributes have limited predictive power.